# jquery datatables change default min-height

Tags: jquery, height, datatables

I am using datatables. ( http://datatables.net/ ) I have created a table. There is a height problem I am struggling to change. I checked the table size with firebug. The table height is set 302px by default. I could not find how to change.I tried to change css unsuccessfully. I appreciate, if anyone helps.

from firebug:

```
.dataTables_wrapper {
    clear: both;
    min-height: 302px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Thanks in advance..
Ozlem

Comment: @user , are you using jquery ???

Comment: yes I am. can you give me a sample code?

Comment: @user , i gave some reference code//

Answer (score 7, accepted):

// you can set the any css property through .css like below

```
$('#id').css('min-height','200');
```

Comment: this was the answer. I am writing for the ones who experienced the same problem: even if you are using the id and it is not happening, double check the id with FireBug..I was trying to use 'dataTables_wrapper' as id, however the id was a kind of renamed by the API table that I used. it was like data_rulesTables_wrapper or sth similar. Thanks to gov again...

Answer (score 20):

Add `px` after `200`.

```
$('#id').css('min-height','200px');
```

Hope it saves somebody 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays I would implement sth like this https://datatables.net/reference/option/fixedColumns.heightMatch, in site.js:

```
$('.dataTables_wrapper').DataTable( {
fixedColumns: {
    heightMatch: 'none'
}});
```

and in site.css:

```
td {
line-height: 45px;}
```